# show php variable in html heading

Tags: php, html

i want to print a php variable in the html h1 tag. Important thing to know is that html is defined within the php as follow:

```
<?php


$test=" <html>

<h1><?php echo (rand(10,1000000)); ?></h1>

</html> ";
echo $test;

?>
```

Comment: send link to question it is dup of, and send link of solved question.

Comment: Just read the complete duplicate - the link is above your question. There are a few ways and you have others here too. It is REALLY basic stuff you can read on the first page of any PHP tutorial

Comment: Your edit shows a completely different construction than the first. You need to use the "." concatenation in your example without the echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following

```
<?php
  $a="hi";
  $prints =" <html>
               <h1> $a</h1>
             </html>";
 echo"$prints";
?>
```

Comment: This will generate syntax error.

Comment: <?php
  $a="hi";
  $prints =" <html>
               <h1> $a</h1>
             </html>";
 echo"$prints";
?>

This will work for sure.I've updated my answer

Comment: @mr.tanmay Thanks with some ammendments your suggestion works

Comment: Bad formatting, no need to use quotes here echo"$prints"; etc - this is not a good solution

Comment: he got his answers, Formatting was not the correct thing he was looking for he was looking for the correct conceptual answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write either 1:

```
<?php 
$a="hi";
?>
<html>
  <h1><?php echo $a;?> </h1>
</html>
```

or 2:

```
<?php 
  $a="hi";
  echo "<html><h1>".$a."</h1></html>";

?>
```

Comment: I have put not that html is within the php, i have updated the question please recheck

Comment: Please take more care in formatting. You had a typo too.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly 'show' php variables by 'echoing' them in the html. For example consider this code.

```
<?php 
        include_once "./php/db.php";
            $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM medtable");
                  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo '<form id="form-'.$row["Product"].'"type="POST">';
                    echo '<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="table-'.$row["Product"].'">';
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo'<td style="width:50%" name="name-'.$row["Product"].'">'.$row["Product"].'</td>';
                    echo '<td style="width:20%"> <input type="number" name="amount" id="num-'.$row["Product"].'" min="0" value="'.$row['Amount'].'"</input></td>';
                    echo '<td style="width:10%">'.$row["Price"]. '</td>';
                    echo '<td id="subtotal-'.$row["Product"].'"style="width:10%" value="'.$row["Subtotal"].'">'.$row["Subtotal"].'</td><input type="hidden" name="hidden-'.$row['Product'].'"id="hidden-'.$row["Product"].'"value="'.$row["Subtotal"].'"</input>';
                    echo '<td style="width:10%"><input type="button"id="'.$row["Product"].'"
                        name="'.$row["Product"].'"class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                         </input></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="product" value="'.$row["Product"].'"></input></td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</table></form>";
                  }
                ?>
```

**As you can see a query is made from a table and html tags are then echod into the html file. Hope this helps :)**

Comment: Horrible solution

Comment: why? @mplungjan

Comment: Completely unreadable. Use heredoc or echo or `<?= ... ?>` - anything is better than echoing html like you do

Comment: @mplungjan maybe be more clear when initially commenting as to why something is 'horrible'. This was also very long ago when I wrote this program.

Comment: Yeah - apologies - just the reams of unreadable code made me shiver